# Finding ancestor Nathan Cohen who was born in Russia and immigrated New York City 1900-1905?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, research-methods, immigration, death-records

My Great Great Grandfather Nathan Cohen was born in Russia.

He had a wife Lissie Bernstein with whom he had a daughter Minnie, born in Vilna sometime around 1886. Lissie died about 2 years later in childbirth, and the newborn didn't survive either.

Sometime between 1900 and 1905, Nathan immigrated to New York City, and Minnie came to join him a few years later (in 1904 or 1907, according to the census).

Minnie married Isidore Stuzin in the Bronx in 1916, after which her father "took off" and started sleeping with women all over the country. He would write letters to his daughter but they became more and more rare as time went on, and she never really knew where he was. At one point, a woman who had been in some sort of relationship with Nathan came to Minnie's store hoping to find him, Minnie had to tell her that she hadn't heard from her father in years.

I got most of this information from my mom, except for Nathan and Lissie's names which I got from Minnie's marriage certificate (my mom didn't know their names). It shouldn't be hard to find info on someone who lived in the United States in the 20th century, but I know hardly anything about my Great Great Grandfather aside from his name which is extremely common.

I can't find any record of Nathan and Minnie living together in the 1910 census or the 1905 New York State census. I also couldn't find a death certificate for a Nathan Cohen on FamilySearch where the spouse's name is Lissie.

Does anyone know how I can find more info, like where he ended up living and when/where he died?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  I am assuming that you are a descendant of Minnie.  If you already have a birth record for Minnie and a marriage record for Nathan and Lissie, then I think next you should focus a question here on finding immigration records for Nathan and Minnie.

Comment: Yes I am a descendant of Minnie. I don't have a birth record for Minnie or a marriage record for Nathan and Lissie, those events would have occurred in Russia (probably in what is now Lithuania), and I haven't been able to find such records. For now I'm focusing on finding records of Nathan from after he immigrated, since it's generally easier to find records from the United States.